# Is there a way to find the positions of a group of points entered in a paint area in Qt?

Tags: qt, qpainter

I'm working on a Qt project that requires the user to enter a group of points in a paint area. I will use QPainter, is there a way to find each point's location (position in terms of x and y) on the paint area?

Comment: Which class will you use for your paint area? How will you handle the "entering" of the point? If you use mouse events, they will give you the mouse positions directly and you don't need anything else.

Comment: yes I will use mouse events, thanx